# Signle Sign On between Cognos and Lotus Domino

Tags: single-sign-on, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, cognos, ltpa

I have some lotus domino servers with single sign on using LTPA tokens.
I want to enable SSO for cognos server too.

Cognos is a sub-domain of domino domain (eg mylotus.com and cognos.mylotus.com).
Lotus version is 8.5.3 and Cognos version is 10.2.1

How can i do it? Is it possible?

Comment: A goog starting point would be in here:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/dm/cognos/security/general/enabling_sso_between_cognos8_and_websphere_portal.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is for Cognos 8 and Websphere. I have already googled for similar solutions but i also need something more specific between Cognos 10 and Domino.